is there a way to translate assembly instructions to uops
I was learning about the way CPU (intel modern CPU) works, and I learned about pipelining / out-of-order execution, speculative, and that assembly instructions are not always mapped to one step that the CPU does, but it can be more instruction abstracted from you  (Uops).
so I was thinking is there a way to make cpu jobs easier, by knowing the real uops that gonna be generated and optimizing that? (so the question is there a way to translate assembly instructions to uops)

If you want to take a look at the complexity involved, go explore https://uops.info/ - the data is collected from real CPUs and may differ between CPU generations.

@teapot418 yeah so core vendors don't have any tools or a way to let you know uops that are generated ?

Secret sauce. Intel is secretive even about less detailed stuff like instruction timing data. If there is a document with this, it is at burn-before-reading read-in-a-designated-bunker secrecy levels.

@teapot418 Not as much of a secret as you might think.  Intel actually documents how many µops each instruction is cracked into and what ports they run on.  However, the documentation is not very accurate.

@younesaskour They have (e.g. Intel has Intel Vtune).  But third party tools are some times better.

The only thing close to mapping op codes to uops is the work of these researchers. They managed to map a list of instructions to uops for the Atom-based CPUs. Search their papers/presentations. However ucode is extremely coupled with the uarch implementation it is shipped to, this include much more internal details that basically everyone but Intel itself knows. It's a RE activity, basically.
